# Prolog recursion with different types

Tags: recursion, prolog

If I have predicates in the following format:

```
edge(a,b,50).
edge(b,c,70).

speed(am,70).
speed(pm,100).
```

How can I write a prolog program where I can say `total(From,To,Time,Duration)`, where time is AM or PM time, duration is total distance of the trip?

Answer (score 1):

if this result if what you're after

```
?- total(a,c,Time,Tot).
Time = am,
Tot = 1.7142857142857142 ;
Time = pm,
Tot = 1.2 ;
false.
```

you can get it with

```
total(From,To,Time,Duration) :-
    distance(From, To, Distance),
    speed(Time, Speed),
    Duration is Distance / Speed.

distance(From, To, Distance) :-
    edge(From, To, Distance).
distance(From, To, Distance) :-
    edge(From, T, DistA),
    distance(T, To, DistB),
    Distance is DistA + DistB.
```

Note there must *not* be cycles in edge/3 graph. Otherwise see any of the many questions about basic graph navigation here on SO.